# How to click page below the dialog

Tags: flutter, overlay, navigator

when I was show `CompositedTransformFollower` widget, I find the dialog intercept click event.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxpMg.png)

```
    final content = CompositedTransformFollower(
      link: _link,
      showWhenUnlinked: false,
      offset: Offset(0, widget.height),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              // close
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black12,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(8)),
            ),
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: contentHeight * entity.scale, //content height
            ),
            child: entity.child, // content view
          )
        ],
      ),
    );


    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: false)
          .push(PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => content,
    ))
        .then((value) {
     // close
    });
```

at first, I show the Pop used `overlay` but when show the other dialog again some mistakes have been made, the `overlay` Pop masked my dialog. I found the [issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27725)

and then, I want to used `Navigator.push` show my Pop, but the dialog intercept click event.

Now how would I do that?